# Setup a Rails app to avoid having to use CORS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, mamp, cors, kentico

I am running a MAMP server with default settings (port 8888) locally, and I have a Rails app running on its default port (3000).

In production, I will be having a Kentico server running that will need to run `GET`, `POST` and `PUT` requests via ajax to the Rails app.

Right now though, I am just wanting to set it up in a way so that locally I can develop this out without having to implement any form of CORS. Since `POST` and `PUT` requests are part of the mix, there's no way I can use `JSONP`.

Is there any way to do this, and if so will it translate to the same way of doing it once in production?

Answer (score 0):

CORS would be the most standards compliant way of doing cross-domain communications. But other options include:

- Set up a proxy server to proxy requests on the server-side to your Rails app
- Use an iframe-based solution. This involves setting up a page on your server that makes same-domain XHR requests. You'd then include this page on the client-side using an iframe, and talk to it via inter-frame communication mechanisms such as postMessage.

Here's an overview of the latter technique: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: I assume this means there's no way to avoid some sort of CORS or cross domain solution. I was hoping since both services are actually going to be housed on the same server there was a way to just set the ports up in a way where the browser wouldn't think this is a cross domain request, but sounds like that's not possible?

Comment: Nope, that's not possible on the client side, since the port is included in the same-origin policy.